# Is there a way to add a shadow/drop shadow to one object in a scene?

Tags: shadows, ambient-occlusion

I wanted to add some sort of drop shadow to the letter G (which is an object) in Eevee but I'm not sure how to.

[image: This is what I want to achieve]

[image: This is how it currently looks for me]

Comment: have you enabled the light Shadow option? Also, in the Properties panel > Render > Shadows, there are some settings for the shadows

Comment: I have yes, although it doesn't seem to change anything. I basically want only one object in the scene to have this shadow and wondered if there was a way to add/force a drop shadow? Or am I thinking too much like photoshop?

Comment: you can play with the sharpness of the shadow, but please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Ok I've uploaded the file :)

Comment: you need to copy the link it gives and paste it here  ;)

Comment: Woops sorry, here it is https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/ndwAqrkJ/

Comment: maybe you want to use compositor? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sIUCoCo0oqM

Comment: Thank you Alex, I will take a look at compositor it looks like something I should get used to :)

Answer (score 2):

I would say:

- In your letter material, disable *Screen Space Refraction*
- Your lights are too strong, lower down their strength and play with their orientation
- Give your *Point.001* light a *Contact Shadow* if you use this light
- Your material node setups are weird

I hope it will fix your problem?

Comment: Brilliant, I've followed these steps and it's doing what I need now :) Yeah the materials are still confusing to me, I was trying to make a gradient after following some YouTube videos and ended up with this as a result. I will have a play around with the lights, is it possible to have a light affect just one object or is that not possible? Thank you for your help too :)

Comment: no it's not possible for the moment except with the Compositor

Comment: Ahh ok I read something about that, I will check it out. Thank you again, you've been a big help.